# I want to get the image data from a stream in Xamarin Forms using XLABS

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get the raw image data from a stream and I am not sure where to go from here. I have a viewmodel and a page where I use the function where I select a picture from a gallery using XLABS.

My viewmodel:

```
public ImageSource ImageSource
{
    get { return _ImageSource; }
    set { SetProperty (ref _ImageSource, value); }
}

private byte[] imageData;

public byte[] ImageData { get { return imageData; } }

private byte[] ReadStream(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public async Task SelectPicture()
{
    Setup ();

    ImageSource = null;


    try
    {
        var mediaFile = await _Mediapicker.SelectPhotoAsync(new CameraMediaStorageOptions
            {
                DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front,
                MaxPixelDimension = 400
            });

        VideoInfo = mediaFile.Path;
        ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mediaFile.Source);

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Status = ex.Message;
    }
}


private static double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
{
    double rtn_value = (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;

    return rtn_value;
}
```

The page where I use the code:

```
MyViewModel photoGallery = null;

photoGallery = new MyViewModel ();

private async void btnPickPicture_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await photoGallery.SelectPicture (); 
    imgPicked.Source = photoGallery.ImageSource; //imgPicked is my  image x:name from XAML.

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will initialize the ImageData property you already have defined on your ViewModel

```
VideoInfo = mediaFile.Path;
ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mediaFile.Source);

// add this line
imageData = ReadStream(mediaFile.Source);
```

Comment: Error: Property or indexer "Project.MyViewModel.ImageData" cannot be assigned to (it is read-only)

Comment: typo, use lower case "imageData"

Comment: The code runs but when I use it in my btnPickPicture_Clicked and write it in the log I get this: 
imgPicked.Source = pG.ImageSource;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (imgPicked.Source);

In the log it says: "Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource"

Comment: imgPicked.Source is a stream - writing it to the console isn't particularly useful

Comment: Oh ok. How do write out the raw image data then? Is it the photoGallery.ImageSource where the raw data is?

Comment: We only added one line of code - I would hope that it would be kind of obvious.  ImageData is your byte[] that should contain the image data.

Comment: The code is at a high level for me, that is why I am slow. So how do I connect the ImageData to my ImgPicked.Source?

Comment: You already have a working image source, why would you replace it?  I presume that you want the raw data so you can do something with it that the imagesource can't do, like save it or upload it.

Comment: I need to store the image externally and I couldnt before because I did not get the raw data (i think). so If i try to store ImagePicked.source on my database now (that takes it as a file) it would work?

Comment: ImageData is the byte[] that contains the image data.  That is what you want to store.

Comment: Ah okay. Then I need to make a public string with the value from the imagedata then so I could send it to my database (which is on another page) that has this code: var createResult =parseAPI.createInfo
    (
     ImageData
    );

Comment: Don't use a string.  Pass it as a byte[].  Parse should have methods to handle that.

Comment: byte [ImageData] like that? How can i reach ImageData on another page?